# Problem adding options to Zend_Form_Element_Select through controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I created a Select ELement in a form.

```
    $parentId = $this -> createElement('select', 'parent_id');
    $parentId -> setLabel("Select a parent menu:")
                -> setRequired(true);
    $parentId->addMultiOption(0, 'None');
    $this->addElement($parentId);
```

Its option have to loaded as per the value passed from the query String or URL. So, in my controller I fetched the values I required from the url and loaded extra item to the element, using following code

```
private function renderParentElement($menu_id, $parent = 0) {
    $mapper = $this -> mapper();
    $select = $mapper -> select();
    $select -> where("parent = ?", $parent)
            -> where("menu_id = ?", $menu_id);
    $menus = $mapper -> fetchAll($select);
    if($menus -> count() > 0) {
        foreach($menus as $menu) {
            $this -> form() -> getElement('parent_id') -> addMultiOption($menu -> id, $menu -> label);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Action method calling the above method is this

```
public function addAction()
{
    $menu = $this->_request->getParam('menu');

        $mapperMenu = new Application_Model_Mapper_Menu();
        $this -> view -> menu = $mapperMenu -> find($menu);

        if($this -> _request -> isPost() && $this -> form() -> isValid($_POST)) {
            $data = $this -> form() -> getValues();
            $menuItem = $this -> model();
            $menuItem -> setParent($data['parent']);
            $menuItem -> setMenu_id($data['menu_id']);
            $menuItem -> setLabel($data['label']);
            $menuItem -> setLink($data['link']);
            $menuItem -> setPage_id($data['page_id']);
            $this -> mapper() -> save($menuItem);

            $this -> _request -> setParam('menu', $data['menu_id']);
            $this -> _forward('index');
        }
        $this -> form() -> populate(array('menu_id' => $menu));
        $this -> renderParentElement($menu, 0);
        $this->view->form = $this -> form();
}
```

**Now everything thing was working fine.** The elements were loaded correctly and displaying correctly as well. 
But when I submitted it, the select box gives error as `1 is not found is the haystack`, here 1 is the value of the item i selected, which is loaded from the controller.

Please help me solve this error !!!

Comment: Are you calling your renderParentElement method when the form is submitted as well? The select element will verify that the value submitted is one of the options.

Comment: No, I am not calling `renderParentElement` method. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the controller part of your code where the form object is setup.

Comment: I think Tim is correct in saying that the options are not getting added again when the form is submitted. Since `renderParentElement` doesn't actually render anything, you might change the name of it to something like `setParentOptions` and call it in the Controller that renders it and (if different) the Controller that processes the form.

Comment: @Tim Fountain, I have updated my question. Please see

Comment: @Just H, Ok, I will change the name of the function, however it is the troubling part..... I have included the action method calling that method... would you please take a look at it.

Comment: what if you put these lines `        $this -> form() -> populate(array('menu_id' => $menu));
        $this -> renderParentElement($menu, 0);
` above the if statement? That should make it so the values exist by the time you call `form->isValid()`

Comment: @Just H, no no its not related with menu_id, its `parent_id` that is being updated later on....., how to populate its multiple options before the submit

Comment: @mrN you at least need to move the line that calls `$this->renderParentElement($menu,0);` to be above the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you have no values in your element before you call isValid

```
$this->renderParentElement($menu, 0);
// you have to set the options in the form before you validate it
if($this->_request->isPost() && $this->form()->isValid($_POST)) { ... }
```

Note that you don't have to call your render method twice, just move it up to before the if statement

Comment: @mrN Glad to help, took me just a minute to spot the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form Zend attempts to match the values passed to the values in your select box. What this error is telling you is that the option with value '1' has not been found in the select. What you need to do is re-populate your select box with your options before you call isValid.

Comment: What you are doing at the moment is submitting the values for the select box via the url (eg: www.somedomain.com/somepage.php?age=1&height=2&circumfrence=3 into <option value="2">height</option>). You are then submitting this form but not the age/height/etc parameters. The result is that the form cannot find the option with value 2. The easiest way to fix this is to submit a hidden input field with an encoded value of the select options then, when the post is submitted, decode the value and populate the select box again.

Comment: Could you give me a example code? I am a beginner so, not sure how to do that.